# Why does the front camera not open, when using Camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using Camera2 API (https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic) for my project.
I want to use Front and Rear both  camera, It’s working properly on my device
Realme5
Android: 10
But when I am trying to use front camera on
One Plus 6, Android: 10 or Samsung Galaxy J7 Nxt, Android 7.0 Or Redmi.
Then I am going on **onConfigureFailed** method  and it’s redirect me firstActivity
**Manifest ScreenShots**:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv6ha.png)

**Log ScreenShots**:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NofCU.png)

**Whole code in googlearchive GitHub link is given above**

**Variable Initialisation**

```
 private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
public static int  mSelectedFacing = 1;
```

**flip camera button click**

```
            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                if(mSelectedFacing ==0){
                    mSelectedFacing = 1;
                }else {
                    mSelectedFacing = 0;
                }
                closeCamera();
                openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight(), mSelectedFacing);

            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }
```

**Open camera**

```
private void openCamera(int width, int height,int mSelectedFacing) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height,mSelectedFacing);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}
```

**Close camera**

```
private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}
```

**CameraPreviewSession**

```
 private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help me …
Thanks in advance

Comment: we aren't going to click on any links, so please include all relevant and specific sections of code in your question, then people will gladly help out

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for response. now I have add some use full code related to this maybe now you can understand. I have already added googlearchive github link  which code i am using  https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 0):

I have do like it will capture image in background without any preview screen using Camera2 API in background service.

Visit https://codepalyers.blogspot.com/2020/12/capture-image-in-background-without.html

If you wish to use rear camera use
private final String frontCamera = "1";
private final String backCamera = "0";
as already define in code.